# Flaky Flash buttons

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm working on this Flash project done with AS3 and for some reason the buttons I've created aren't always responding to clicks. Sometimes I need to click two or three times before the actual click comes through.

Has anyone experienced similar issues?

Comment: Cant say I've ever experienced that, can you post a minimal working example of the problem?

Comment: Are you using transparent or opaque wmode?

Comment: @Kane: So far I have not been able to replicate the issue in a minimal working program. The odd behavior only seems to occur in my larger app.
@Cay: No wmode mode used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should look, whether the clicks, mouse ups and mouse downs are trigger on the stage, and if so, what their target is ... this should give you a good hint to where the problem is ...

if they are not triggered, the only explanation coming to my mind is, it's either a flash player bug, or you are having performance problems making your app unresponsive ...

greetz

back2dos